# Status of network ports

Tags: networking, c++, netstat

I hope it is possible to get the necessary details of each network port from `/etc/services`. If I have to develop a C++ program to get the status of each port how should I start it?  I am not allowed to call `netstat`, `ss` or anything similar from my program. Is there some files in the filesystem from which I can get the information?

Comment: >> netstat -ano | find "portnumber" for Windows

>> netstat -anp | grep "portnumber" for Linux

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there some other method other than giving each port number manually?

Comment: @vembutech : Also if I give `netstat -anp | grep 266`, it lists all ports containing the substring 266.

Comment: @Anzz unless you're writing a script, you may want to lower your standards. In most cases greping for the port number works because in that case all you're really trying to do is eliminate _most_ of the unrelated ports. Most people are alright with a few possible false positives since they can just ignore them.

Comment: What details do you need to display? What operating system?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: I need to display the port number, the protocol and its status.

Comment: You can call [getservent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getservent.3.html) repeatedly to get static data about every service (port number, protocol, descriptive name). Can you tell us what *status* means and what operating system must be supported?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: status is whether the port is listening, active or inactive. I am using ubuntu14, but would like to know the details for all distributions.

Comment: Does *active* simply mean *connected*, or do you need to see a certain rate of data being transferred to qualify as *active*?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: No, just to know if it is connected or not.

Comment: What are you supposed to show when a port both has an active connection but is also listening for additional connections?

Comment: If possible both,otherwise listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not clear to me whether you want to implement `netstat -a -t -u` or the outer join of `/etc/services` and `netstat -a -t -u`, or something else, but here are some ideas that may help:

- TCP and UDP port numbers range from 1 to 65536. The `/etc/services` file that you mentioned lists a *subset* of the [well-known ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) and [registered ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Registered_ports). A larger list is at [the IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt). You can use [getservent()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getservbyname.3.html) to retrieve each record listed in `/etc/services`.
- On Linux, you can get a list of all the sockets that are in listen, connecting, connected, or partially closed state, and their local and remote addresses and ports, by reading the files `/proc/net/tcp`, `/proc/net/tcp6`, `/proc/net/udp`, and `/proc/net/udp6`. The output of `netstat -a -t -u -n` is almost exactly the same as these files, just a lot prettier. The addresses, port numbers, and states are in hex. The pretty version of the state field can be produced by using the names in `/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h`:

```
    enum
    {
      TCP_ESTABLISHED = 1,
      TCP_SYN_SENT,
      TCP_SYN_RECV,
      TCP_FIN_WAIT1,
      TCP_FIN_WAIT2,
      TCP_TIME_WAIT,
      TCP_CLOSE,
      TCP_CLOSE_WAIT,
      TCP_LAST_ACK,
      TCP_LISTEN,
      TCP_CLOSING
    };
```

- On FreeBSD, you would call `sysctlbyname("net.inet.tcp.pcblist",...)`, which retrieves an array of `xtcpcb` structs. It's probably best to look at the `netstat` source code to see how to interpret those structures.

Answer (score 2):

`netstat` is *the* tool to use for basic knowledge of network connections. You didn't specify what OS you were on but I'll assume Linux in which case `netstat -tun | awk '{ if ($4 ~ ":<portNumber>") print }'` should do most of what you're wanting. That prints all TCP and UDP sockets and selects for something that ends in a colon and port number you're after.

For example, looking for people connected to `sshd` on my system.

```
[root@xxx5b ~]# netstat -tun | awk '{ if ($4 ~ ":22") print }'
tcp        0     64 10.xxx.5.140:22             10.xxx.255.178:51976         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.xxx.5.140:22             10.xx.255.178:58535         ESTABLISHED
[root@xxx5b ~]#
```

If you don't like the `awk` you can always just `netstat -tun | less` and just visually scan the output. If there isn't a port listed in `netstat` there's something seriously wrong with your system.

Comment: Can I know from where netstat gets the info about ports..Is there some files in the filesystem that contains these info.

Comment: If you're on linux I suppose you could look at `/proc/net/tcp` and `/proc/net/udp` but I'll also have to ask why you want to do that. I don't know the details of how `netstat` functions internally, but it's function as a utility is to research network connections.

Comment: I looked into those folders..Yes I am on linux and there are two other files also in `/proc/net` -`tcp6` and `udp6`. But I was not sure about its contents..

Comment: Those are the IPv6 files. The ones I listed are the older ones used for IPv4.

Comment: My ultimate objective is to developna program to get the status of all network ports.. So  i have to know from where I will get the required info..

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `netstat` (or alternatively `ss`)? It seems like rewriting these programs is probably going to take more effort from you than it's going to return in benefit. It's not just about knowing where the files are located, you have to convert the endian order of the hex numbers in those files (networks are Big Endian, IP addresses are listed in little endian), you'll have to re-write logic that traces an open port to a particular PID to show process information, etc.

Comment: I have to use C++. And not allowed to directly call netstat or ss from the program.

Comment: When posting questions about homeworks, it's better to say it explicitly in the question. Also it's good to ask for information that you actually want and to specify the limitations as well. Your question in its current form suggest that you just didn't get the usage of netstat. Rewrite the question and you'll get better answers.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command:

```
nmap localhost -p 0-65535
```

This will list all the open ports on your system.

Comment: From where does nmap gets this information..

Comment: From /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services file. See this: http://nmap.org/book/nmap-services.html

Comment: While nmap works, there are better tools to learn the information from the system like netstat with various options. The problem with nmap is that it actually attempts to connect to all of the services, which is not necessary at all.